# Append generic element to Realm List

Tags: swift, realm, realm-list

I'm trying to set data in a Realm database in swift via Object schema properties. Add new objects has been straightforward (and also relate and object to another), but I can't fin the way to append objects to a List property.

Let's see the snippet of code I use to create objects and add to Realm database:

```
func save(elements: [String : Any], realmClassName: String, realm: Realm, listObject: Object) {
    // Ge properties for Realm Object subclass with name realmClassName
    let properties = realm.schema[realmClassName]

    // Iterate through elements array
    for element in elements {
        // Instantiate Realm Object through its name (realmClassName)
        let thisClass: AnyClass = NSClassFromString("\(namespace).\(name)")!
        let realmClass = thisClass as! Object.Type
        let object = realmClass.init()

        // Iterate though Object Schema properties
        for property in properties?.properties as [Property]! {
           object[property.name] = element[property.name]
        }

        // Add Object to Realm database
        realm.add(object)

       // Here is where I want to append object to Object List
    }
 }
```

Question is, how to do something similar to:

```
listObject.append(object)
```

Some attempt trow error like:

```
Could not cast value of type 'RealmSwift.List<AppName.Cars>' (0x1117446d8) to 'RealmSwift.List<RealmSwift.Object>'
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is the actual line of code throwing the error? It seems like you left that line out accidentally. Btw your code has nothing to do with generics, your function isn't a generic function.

Comment: Sorry, by 'generics' I mean not to hard type the name of the RealmObject, like Cars. My fault to use 'generics' (T in swift).